# Index was out of range.. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop

This is my code :

```
for (i = j; i <= e.curpos; i++)
        {               
            Question q = e.questions[i];-- here exception is occuring
            // display details of question
            dr = dts.NewRow();
            dr["no"] = i+1;
            dr["enterquestion"] = q.enterquestion;
            dr["optiona"] = q.optiona;
            dr["optionb"] = q.optionb;
            dr["optionc"] = q.optionc;
            dr["optiond"] = q.optiond;
            dts.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

`Question q = e.questions[i]` here after the loop complete the exception is occurring

Comment: What's e ? What's j ? Hard to say what's wrong without knowing all of your code...

Comment: e is obj of Examination Class file and Question is also a class file and j is a variable

Comment: How does `e.curpos` relate to the number of elements in `e.questions`?  For this code to work, `e.curpos` must be _less than_ `e.quesions.Length`.  If `e.curpos` is _equal to_ `e.questions.Length`, then just change the `i <= e.curpos` to be `i < e.curpos`.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong is e.curpos is equal to or greater than e.questions.length, or j is less than 0. You'll need to use a breakpoint or write to the console log to see which value is incorrect.